# ngClick inside of ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Using Ionic framework I'm trying to create a clickable list using Angular.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <span *ngClick="showDevice(device)">
      {{ device }}
    </span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The error report is that `ngClick is not a property of span`. Changing `span` to `ng-template` just gives me the same error. Putting the code like this

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices" *ngClick="showDevice(device)">
    {{ device }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

it says `cannot have multiple bindings on one attribute`. It also says back `...verify it as part of this module` which I do not makes sense.

Any idea how to put the ngClick in a ngFor loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <span (click)="showDevice(device)">
      {{ device }}
    </span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

or this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices" (click)="showDevice(device)">
    {{ device }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Any idea why it didn't work with *ngClick?

Comment: Click events in angular2 is as above. Your approach can potentially be for angularjs. Either way, you can't use two directives on the same div in angular2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (click) instead of *ngClick. it will look something like this.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <div (click)="showDevice(device)">
      {{ device }}
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: in angular 2 their is nothing like *ngClick. it was in angularJS(previous version) which was used as ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

ng-click is angular v1 syntax, you should use just **`(click)`** with angular

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices" (click)="showDevice(device)">
    {{ device }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```